# How to take a sub string of a string in java depending on both character

Tags: java, string, oop

Suppose i have a string array like:-

```
str[0] = [ name : pankaj ]
str[1] = [ sex : male ]
str[2] = [ age : 25 ] 
...........
...........
```

like this I am having some 10 element string

Now i have a function in which i am passing this string array and one key example

```
getvalue(str,key)
```

here key value is name this is my function definition

```
 public String (String[] str , String key){
    }
```

in this function i need output as **pankaj** which is name attribute value
if I pass a key age then i need output **25**

In such case that value is not possible that time return null .

Now i want to ask weather we have any inbuilt function for this purpose if not then which is more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Why can't you use `Map<String, List<String>>` here?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map of some type. Like a HashMap:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

I would scan through the array and build a `HashMap` with the key, value pairs in them.

You can then easily query the `Map`.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String s: str) {
    String[] split = s.split(" : ");
    map.put(split[0].substring(3), split[1].substring(0, split[1].length-3);
}
```

Then to query it just do:

```
map.get("key");
```

The exact offsets in `substring`, etc will need tweaking to get the correct value out. You also may want to `trim()` the `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Although Maps should be faster (or at least more predictable), if you must use a String[], try the following method:

```
public String getValue(String[] str, String key){
    for (String s : str){
        String[] pair = s.split(":");
        if (pair[0].equals(key)){
            return pair[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Map in this case.
A [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) is an object that maps keys to values.Use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) Here is the [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-hashmap-tutorial-java/) of hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over your String array and for each entry invoke split(":")

Read the API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
for (String sEntry : str) {
    String[] arrSplittedEntries = sEntry.split(":");
    if (key.equals(arrSplittedEntries[0])) {
        return arrSplittedEntries[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess your string input to map to make effective queries:

```
static HashMap<String, String> process(String[] pairs) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    for (String s : pairs) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        m.find();
        String key = m.group();
        m.find();
        String value = m.group();
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Then you can just work with map

```
System.out.println(map.get("sex")); // male
System.out.println(map.get("put")); // null
```